# IDEA - Not detecting changes in build.gradle

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I used to be told and annoyed upon every change I put down on build.gradle or settings.gradle.

However, lately after messing some things up on the project structure, I don't have this feature anymore.

Any way to turn this back on? I miss it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, the gradle is simply not refreshed or not configured properly. Go to your gradle task bar (Mine is situated on the right hand side of the screen) and press the refresh icon to get it back